# Can this water damage to my Canon T6 be repaired?

Tags: equipment-damage, water

My Canon T6 got wet at a waterfall; the battery did not get wet. I let the camera dry out for weeks - it apparently works now but is giving me totally white images.

Is there any chance this damage can be repaired?

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly not fixable without professional skills. Unfortunately, the cost of the repair is also going to be higher than the value of the camera (the T6 aka 1300D was Canon's entry level DSLR in 2016) so honestly at this point your best bet is to purchase a new camera.

Comment: ...and a waterproof case.

Answer (score 3):

Did you remove the battery immediately after the camera got wet and while drying out the camera? If not, electrolysis will happen between conductors and dissolve wiring which will cause the camera to malfunction. Unfortunately, this could be very difficult to fix, and as Philip stated, not economically fixable.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like water is stuck in/on electric circuitry around sensor.

You want to send it to Canon services for a proper repair, including eventually piece replacement. They will evalutate the repair cost and then ask you if you want to proceed.

This is valid wether you are under warranty or not.

Comment: I think we can be sure enough in this case that it's a write-off that it's not worth the expense of sending it to Canon. At this point, that's just throwing good money after bad.

Comment: Canon factory service very often will refuse to repair internal water damage, especially if there's any hint whatsoever of salt + water involved. The reason being that there's no way to know what else was affected and will corrode enough to go bad during the period the repair is under warranty.